# Missing variable in silex, php

Tags: php, silex

we are creating blog in Silex and we have a problem with variable **$posts_id**. After we are trying to use it in $data it is always int 0 no matter its previous value. We are unable to generate next page, which would be view of page of post with all visible comments with variable posts_id matching id of post. 
Here are our functions:

```
public function addAction(Application $app, Request $request)
{
    $posts_id = (int)$request->get('posts_id');

    $data = array(
        'comment' => 'Comment',
        'date' => date('Y-m-d H:m:s'),
        'posts_id' => $posts_id
    );
    $form = $app['form.factory']
        ->createBuilder(new CommentForm(), $data)->getForm();
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $data = $form->getData();
        $model = $this->_model->addComment($data);
        return $app->redirect(
            $app['url_generator']->generate(
                'posts_view', array('id' => $data['posts_id'])
            ), 301
        );
    }
    $this->_view['form'] = $form->createView();
    $app['session']->getFlashBag()->add(
        'message', array(
            'type' => 'success', 'content' => $app['translator']->trans('New comment added.')
        )
    );
    return $app['twig']->render(
        'comments/add.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'posts_id' => $posts_id
        )
    );
}


public function addComment($data)
{
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO comments
    (comment, date, posts_id)
    VALUES (?,?,?)';
    $this->_db
        ->executeQuery(
            $sql,
            array(
                $data['comment'],
                $data['date'],
                $data['posts_id']
            )
        );
}
```

}

Comment: $posts_id = (int)$request->get('posts_id'); < where is this coming from and what is it returning?

Comment: It is returning id of currently viewed post and at this point it is working perfectly. But the value is changed later to int 0.

Comment: when exactly is the "later" part you are talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables inside function are not global, means you need to instantiate Request again inside addComment() function

```
public function addComment($data, Request $request)
{

    $posts_id = (int)$request->get('posts_id');
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO comments
    (comment, date, posts_id)
    VALUES (?,?,?)';
    $this->_db
        ->executeQuery(
            $sql,
            array(
                $data['comment'],
                $data['date'],
                $data['posts_id']
            )
        );
}
```

Comment: By "later" part I mean everything that is below this line. When we are using var_dump right after this line, we get int 2 for example. But doing the same below
    $data = array(
        'comment' => 'Comment',
        'date' => date('Y-m-d H:m:s'),
        'posts_id' => $posts_id
    );
will result in int 0.

Comment: you are not invoking $posts_id again, variable inside function are not global, unless you specify them with class contructor (__construct()), means in addComment() function you need to get it "again", $posts_id = $request->get('posts_id');

Comment: Oh, I see. You're right, that was mistake in our way of thinking. Thank you very much for your help.